# Woocommerce view-order link without my-account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want make a url like this: `www.pagename.com/view-order/999/`
and it's shows order details. How can do it without going true `my-account/view-roder/999` ? if i remove my-account it redirects to `/view-order/`

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Do you have any script? at least something to start with?

Comment: No, i have not any script because i don't know where to start. In woocommerce settings i tried to change view-order endpoint to view_order. Created new page with view_order slug. Added link 
 ?page_id=888&view_order=999. After link click it sill redirects to /view_order/ and thats all what i can think off.. Tryed to look in google, but no success

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Order Received URL":

```
$order->get_checkout_order_received_url()
```